# Embedded C AVR Bit stuffing an array

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr

Can anyone help me with some code i need to implement bit stuffing on an array of data? The program is for an AVR micro-controller (Tiny84A) using GNU C.

```
unsigned char datas[3] = {00011111,10000001,00000000};
```

To add 0 to each set of 5 one’s i.e. after every five consecutive 1′s appear a zero

Therefore data should be

```
00011111,10000001 becomes 00011111 01000000 10000000
```

I'm unsure where to start, an example would be great!

Comment: Good and what is the problem you have?

Comment: Basically i'm stuck on how to implement the routine. Not sure where to begin.

Comment: It is unclear how `0b00011111,0b00000001` goes to `00001111 10000000 10000000`.  1) show some code, 2) show more examples 3) explain better.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. 
00011111,10000001 becomes 00011111 01000000 10000000 when 5 consecutive 1's appear in a row and a '0' is inserted. Therefore the data is shifted right due to the insert of an extra '0'

Comment: You are shifting to the "right" within a `char`.  Note: Shifting the LSbit from `datas[x]` to be the MSbit at `datas[x+1]` is not necessarily shifting right nor left.  At best it is an Endian thing.  Do not know if AVR is big or little endian.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of examples on the web for bit stuffing (inserting a 0 after 5 1s). Unfortunately, many of them involve reading and writing strings of characters 0 and 1.

There are also examples of bit streams. It looks like you need to find examples of each and combine them.

You need to expand your question to explain more of the design decisions you have made.

In particular, it looks like you are expecting the input to be in an array instead of a stream. Are you expecting to write the output to the same array? That is a little bit trickier than writing to a different array. A stream of bits would be different again.

The basic idea is to keep counters of where you are in the input and output streams, and load and write bytes appropriately as you reach the end of 8 bits.

```
unsigned char datas[3] = {00011111,10000001,00000000};    
int in_byte, in_bit, out_byte, out_bit;

void init()
{
    in_byte = 0; in_bit = 0; out_byte = 0; out_bit = 0;
}

int get_bit()
{
    int ret = 0;

    if (datas[in_byte] & 1 << (7 - in_bit))
    {
        ret = 1;
    {

    ++in_bit;
    if (in_bit == 8)
    {
        in_bit = 0;
        ++in_byte;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

You have to write your own `void put_bit(int bit)`, but it is similar using the "or" operator `|`.

You also need to make a function to do the loop that counts up to 5 and puts an extra 0. Look at the examples on the web for that.